# AWS : dynamodb.restoreTableFromBackup is not a function

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use lambda to restore a table in dynamoDB, 
but keep getting this error message.

```
TypeError: dynamodb.restoreTableFromBackup is not a function
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?
Thanks~

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#restoreTableFromBackup-property

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const params = {
        BackupArn: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1/xxxxx',
        TargetTableName: 'xxx',
    };
    dynamodb.restoreTableFromBackup(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data); // successful response
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the code you provided in my own lambda and got the same result.
It seems the AWS SDK that is provided natively in Lambda isn't the latest version, with the restoreTableFromBackup function.

If I do the same test while using the latest available in npm, it seems to work fine.

As a work around, I suggest uploading your lambda as a zip file, and including the the node_modules/aws-sdk along with your code.

This will ensure it uses the latest aws-sdk which includes the restoreTableFromBackup function.

To assist further, I've written a walk through of how to use On-Demand backups / restore and how to schedule these backups.

https://www.abhayachauhan.com/2017/12/dynamodb-scheduling-on-demand-backups

HTH

Answer (score 0):

'npm install aws-sdk' in Cloud9 terminal for the Lambda